# WCSession - PayloadTooLarge

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Apple Documentation shows:

> `PayloadTooLarge` -
>   An error indicating that the item being sent exceeds the maximum size limit. This type of error can occur for both data dictionaries and files.
>   Available in watchOS 2.0 and later.

Does anyone know what the max size limits are for both these methods are for transferring data from the watch to the phone?:

```
func transferUserInfo(_ userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) -> WCSessionUserInfoTransfer
```

and

```
func transferFile(_ file: NSURL,
         metadata metadata: [String : AnyObject]?) -> WCSessionFileTransfer
```

I can't find it documented anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding userInfo

> transferUserInfo:

and even for complication info:

> transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:

the size limit (iOS 9) is **65.5 kB**, the same for messages you can use with

> sendMessage:

The size limit for

> updateApplicationContext:

is **262 kB**.

Regarding

> transferFile:

ccjensen's answer is correct as my experience there is **no actual limit** even the Apple doc mentioned in the WCSession error code section that the file could be too big:

> WCErrorCodePayloadTooLarge An error indicating that the item being
>   sent exceeds the maximum size limit. This type of error can occur for
>   both data dictionaries and files.

This part of the documentation is not really clear so you have to check it always before  using it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about user info, but I haven't hit any limits yet on file size (as long as the watch has enough free space).