# userInfoTransfer, payload is too big

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to send a fair bit of data from a watchOS app, to the iOS app. The data is comprised of generated content on the watch. This data is stored in Core Data on the watch. So I'm not actually transferring a file, in which case I'd use `transferFile`. I've attempted to use `transferFile` in this case, but a file URL is required. Since I'm not actually transferring a file, I'm not sure what to do.

According to this:
[WCSession - PayloadTooLarge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683648/wcsession-payloadtoolarge)

I'm currently limited to 65.5kb. My average transfer requirements are from 0 - in the megabytes. Most are probably between 0 - 400kb.

How can I transfer this data?

I guess I could break it up? However that would be a bit hackish, as I'd also need code in the iOS app to piece it back together before use.

This is my call to `transferUserInfo`:

```
func sendDictionary(dict: [String: Any]) {
    WCSession.default().transferUserInfo(dict)
}
```

`dict` is a dictionary object from a Core Data query.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried transferring the file that is storing the Core Data SQLite database using `NSPersistentStore.url`?

Comment: @DaveWeston Ah, I would prefer not to do that, as it would make things a bit more complicated than I'd like. I think i'd prefer to implement the segmented transfer idea :/

Comment: The other thing you can try is writing the dictionary to a binary plist file and transfer that. Since transferUserInfo requires a property list compatible dictionary, that option should be straightforward for you.

Comment: @DaveWeston Oh yeah, thats a good idea.

Comment: Anyone browsing this question, I used @DaveWeston 's idea as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the dictionary as JSON on disc, then sending that as Data with transferfile() and cleaning up the file afterwards?

Comment: Please see comment above. This is essentially what I did, but not as json, a plist file instead.